# Is it true that is $P^n=\langle a^n\rangle$ such that n is a positive integer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $R$ be principal ideal domain that is a local. Let $P$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. Let $P$ be generated by an element $a$ (i.e. $P=\langle a\rangle$). Is it true that is $P^n=\langle a^n\rangle$ such that $n$ is a positive integer? How could I prove that?

Comment: Note: for ideals $I$ and $J$, $IJ$ is the ideal spanned by elements of the form $ab$ with $a \in I$ and $b \in J$

Comment: Are we given that this is a commutative ring?

Comment: R is integral ideal domain that is local

Comment: I'm not sure what definitions are common... is that a yes then?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I should say $R$ is principal ideal domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any commutative ring, the answer is yes.

You can proceed inductively with a proof like
$$
r \in P^{n-1}P \implies\\
r = \sum_j\left(\sum_i b_{ij}a^{n-1} \right)\left(\sum_i c_{ij}a \right) = 
\sum_k d_k a^n \implies\\
r \in P^n
$$

Comment: If we consider a is not nilpotent, then the statement will be true?

Comment: Even then, not necessarily.  Take $a = 2 \in \Bbb Z_{12}$, for example.

Comment: Could I ask you what is the meaning of $P^n$?

Answer (score 0):

YES. Because,  If $R $ is a commutative ring then its maximal ideal is principal, so the generator of it, up to association, is the unique prime element of $R$ and every ideal of $R$ is a power of it.